# Run a windows service as NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM

Tags: windows-services

Is there a way to run a windows local service with the integrated account NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM ? (basically specify the "log on as" as NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM)

Thanks,
Fred

Comment: Odd question. SYSTEM (i.e. LocalSystem) is the default account configured when creating a service via [`CreateService`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682450).